# why does my sprite jump through other sprites randomly in xamarin.ios?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, sprite-kit, xamarin.ios

i am currently trying to create a platform game in xamarin for ios. i have a character sprite who i'm moving with the ApplyForce method of PhysicsBody, which only has a inputted value for the x direction. So my problem is that a little bit after my character moves to the right, it suddenly jumps up to the 3rd level from the 1st, gets stuck in the level's physics body, and runs back and forth inside that PhysicsBody. Because of this i cannot make my sprite jump either.

I've set the character to `sp.PhysicsBody.Dynamic = true;`, but the levels(basically platforms that span the entire screen, there are 6 of them on screen) are `level.PhysicsBody.Dynamic = false;`.Both have `UsesPreciseCollisionDetection` set to true so the program should know if the two physicsbodys are colliding, but for some reason it allows them to phase through eachother anyway.

sp is my character sprite, and c is the class in which i create the character. i generate the character at the left side of the screen.

switchDirection is a method i created that just changes the texture of the character when going in the opposite direction.

c.right is a boolean that tells the code whether sp is going right or left

i call `checkDirectionPhysics` in `Update` in the GameScene class

```
public void checkDirectionPhysics()
    {
        //sp.PhysicsBody.Velocity = new CGVector(30, 0);

        if (sp.Position.X >= Frame.Width - sp.Size.Width)
        {
            c.switchDirection(2, (float)sp.Position.X, (float)c.curLevelY);//(float)sp.Position.Y);
            sp.PhysicsBody.ApplyForce(new CGVector(-95, 0));
            c.right = false;

        }

        else if (c.right == true && sp.Position.X >= Frame.GetMinX())
        {
            //c.switchDirection(1, (float)sp.Position.X, (float)sp.Position.Y);
            sp.PhysicsBody.ApplyForce(new CGVector(95, 0));

        }

        else if (c.right == false && sp.Position.X <= Frame.GetMinX() + sp.Size.Width + 5f)
        {
            c.switchDirection(1, (float)sp.Position.X, (float)c.curLevelY);//(float)sp.Position.Y);
            sp.PhysicsBody.ApplyForce(new CGVector(95, 0));
            c.right = true;

        }   

        else if (c.right == false && sp.Position.X >= Frame.GetMinX())
        {
            //c.switchDirection(2, (float)sp.Position.X, (float)sp.Position.Y);
            sp.PhysicsBody.ApplyForce(new CGVector(-95, 0));

        }   
    }
```

In my TouchesBegan method, i have this to make my character jump to the next level, and set the current level y value to increase to the next level's height. (The value that goes in the y direction is not nearly enough to make the character jump to the next level yet, ill figure that out after i solve this issue) After the current level is the 5th level, it resets the level back to one so i could see where it was, purely for debugging.

```
        foreach (var touch in touches)
        {
                sp.PhysicsBody.ApplyImpulse(new CGVector(10, 50));
            if (c.curLevelY < Frame.Height / 6 * 4)
            {
                c.curLevelY += Frame.Height / 6 * 1;
            }
            else
            {
                c.curLevelY = Frame.Height / 6 * 1;
            }

        }
```

This is all the code that i could think of that has anything to do with moving the character sprite. I hope its enough, and if its not please let me know what else is needed! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: what are the category bit masks and the collision bit masks set to?

Comment: btw, when you set dynamic = false, everything on this object gets ignored (Which is exactly what you want) so you do not need precision turned on for it

Comment: im sorry im fairly new to this, i dont even know what those are. could the default value(if there is one) of those be affecting me?

Comment: yup, I think categoryBitMask default is 0, so this means it has no identification

Comment: oh okay, thanks! ill change that in my code

Comment: do you recommend any websites with detailed info on catergoryBitMask's? im looking at apples page and i dont see anything that describes this

Comment: lol, check out the documentation here on SO